# Adding an extra step with details in checkout process in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, websites

I am developing a website http://canadadrugsinc.com/ similar to https://onlinegenericmedicinestore.com/

Before checkout page I need an extra page "Medical Condition" who takes few information and one file (Medical Prescription) from the customer same as ADC(alldaychemist)

My Magento version is 2.1 and Used Theme is Bewaqoof.

Comment: Hey there, your website and the rest do not use Magento, but Wordpress (installed Woocommerce plugin). Please post your question in WordPress Stack Exchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Btw, both sites use **Flatsome** theme, not Bewaqoof.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - WordPress. Note: WordPress Stack Exchange option does not available when choose "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"